# Python Selenium Unable to Locate element by xpath

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

Hi I am trying to use selenium to make a website bot. Everyone talks about them nowdays and I am curious about how they work. So this is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

print("Opening Window")
driver.get("https://store.nvidia.com/de-de/geforce/store/?page=1&limit=9&locale=de-de&search=geforce%20rtx%203060%20ti")
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/app-root/product/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/product-details/div/ul/li[1]/ul[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/button')



driver.implicitly_wait(10)
print("Closing Window")
driver.quit()
```

I get the error code:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/app-root/product/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/product-details/div/ul/li[1]/ul[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/button"}
  (Session info: chrome=97.0.4692.99)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    Ordinal0 [0x00BFFDC3+2555331]
    Ordinal0 [0x00B977F1+2127857]
    Ordinal0 [0x00A92E08+1060360]
    Ordinal0 [0x00ABE49E+1238174]
    Ordinal0 [0x00ABE69B+1238683]
    Ordinal0 [0x00AE9252+1413714]
    Ordinal0 [0x00AD7B54+1342292]
    Ordinal0 [0x00AE75FA+1406458]
    Ordinal0 [0x00AD7976+1341814]
    Ordinal0 [0x00AB36B6+1193654]
    Ordinal0 [0x00AB4546+1197382]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00D99622+1619522]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00E4882C+2336844]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00C923E1+541697]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00C91443+537699]
    Ordinal0 [0x00B9D18E+2150798]
    Ordinal0 [0x00BA1518+2168088]
    Ordinal0 [0x00BA1660+2168416]
    Ordinal0 [0x00BAB330+2208560]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x75DEFA29+25]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77307A9E+286]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77307A6E+238]
```

I do wait 5 seconds for the page to load, but still it can't find xpath. I triplechecked that the xpath was right, and if I search for the xpath in the chrome inspect windows, it can find it.
The problem could be switching the iframe, but the website doesn't use iframes I think. Here is the website URL: https://store.nvidia.com/de-de/geforce/store/?page=1&limit=9&locale=de-de&search=geforce%20rtx%203060%20ti

Comment: Which element is that? there are exactly 32 buttons, we cannot assume which one you are referring with this xpath `/html/body/app-root/product/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/product-details/div/ul/li[1]/ul[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/button`

Comment: @cruisepandey He will not accept the answer anyway :)

Comment: @Prophet: But you were too quick :P

Comment: Needs debugging details
The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @cruisepandey why not isn't xpath uniqe?

Answer (score 0):

Selenium looks good.

Your locator is not appropriate so you can use the following one:

1- Absolute xpath:
`//html/body/app-root/product/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/product-details/div/div/div/div[3]/div[3]/button`

2- Relative xpath:
`(//button[@class='compare'])[1]`

**Note:** you can change the value of index depending on which index(button) you want to interact.

3- css-selector:
`button[class='compare']`

Comment: Now it stopped giving an error but it still doesnt click. I tried simulating it by using `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//html/body/approot/product/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/product-details/div/div/div/div[3]/div[3]/button').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)` Still doesnt click